# Как можно выбрать отображать ли поле в ACF?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, acf

Есть поле "Группа" и нужно сделать так, чтобы можно было выбирать - отображать это поле или нет с помощью чекбокса в админке. Как это можно сделать? Буду благодарен Вам за помощь)

Comment: Когда создаете поле, там есть такая вещь как Conditional Logic (условная логика), там Вы можете настроить это таким образом чтобы в зависимости от значения чекбокса отображать это поле/группу или скрывать, если речь об админке.

Comment: Если речь о темплейте, то просто оборачиваете в проверку `if(get_field('some_field'))`, тот кусочек разметки где оно должно выводиться.